# Почему некорректно работает сортировка по полю в связующей таблице?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Имеется вот такой код:

```
includes(:ratings).order('ratings.rate DESC')
```

Обернут он в `scope` и вызывается таким образом:

```
@posts = policy_scope(@blog.posts).order_by_rating.page(params[:page])
```

Суть в том, что нужно отсортировать `posts` по их `ratings`.

Этот код работает, но только локально.

А на сервере он работает некорректно. Выводится список с постами, кол-во которых ниже указанного `limit`. И нет пагинации (kaminari). Как только убираю scope `order_by_rating`, то все отображается нормально.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: То, что у вас на сервере и локально разные результаты, тревожный симптом. Установите, какое именно отличие между ними приводит к такому эффекту. Так станете на шаг ближе к разгадке того, почему это произошло и как это починить.

Comment: @D-side с помощью `to_sql` вывел запрос и локально, и на сервере. Сравнение показало что они идентичны.

Comment: Проверяйте дальше. БД одинаковы (тип, версия)? Локально запускали в продакшн-режиме? Версии библиотек одинаковы (по идее `Gemfile.lock` это гарантирует, но на всякий случай)?

Comment: @D-side с таким вообще впервые сталкиваюсь и осознаю что это максимально неадекватно. Также должен уточнить что конфиги приложения (5.1.4) по большей части дефолтные. Особенно те, что касаются настроек AR.

Comment: @D-side да, деплой идет на Docker с копированием таких файлов, как `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: @D-side коннект к разным БД, но они идентичны (дамп). В любом случае это не может (ну или не долнжо) быть из-за данных в БД.

Comment: @D-side локально в production среде работает нормально.

Comment: По всей видимости, у вас на сервере просто другой код ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @D-side а вот если бы все было так просто... Код актуальный.

Comment: Вы уже неоднократно ошибались в своих наблюдениях ранее, так что предлагаю добавить в вопрос детально, что вы выяснили и какими именно способами.

Comment: @D-side код актуальный потому, что при деплое он берется из репозитория + я руками проверил содержимое контейнера. Насчет БД - они разные, но архитектура одинаковая. Плюс записей в обоих случаях более 1000.

Comment: Предыдущий комментарий всё ещё актуален. Компьютеры ничего не выдумывают, они делают что им сказано. Если детерминированный алгоритм даёт различные результаты, значит он работает в различных условиях.

Comment: @D-side ну я же здесь создал вопрос не просто так. Я пытался самостоятельно выявить проблему. У меня не вышло. Я обратился за помощью к местному комьюнити. Используемый код я привел. Поведение также постарался описать.

Comment: Коммьюнити само по себе ничего не сможет вам подсказать по этим деталям -- проект-то ваш, код у вас, как настраивались среды знаете только вы. Если вам нужна помощь от коммьюнити -- потребуются ещё детали. Как выглядит ассоциация, через которую вы сортируете? Как выглядит SQL?